# upload image from external URL using file_get_contents in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

First of all sorry for my bad English !
I'm currently using file upload in Codeigniter , but it's unable to input external URL in my file open dialog ( on Mac os X ) , therefore I need to use file_get_contents to fetch image and upload , it's successfully to upload and show preview , except it cannot insert to database , I'm newbie in code !

this is my code in controller :

```
public function img_upload()
{
if(isset($_POST["image_url"]))
{
    $message = '';
    $image = '';
    if(filter_var($_POST["image_url"], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
        $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif");
        $url_array = explode("/", $_POST["image_url"]);
        $image_name = end($url_array);
        $image_array = explode(".", $image_name);
        $extension = end($image_array);
        if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))
{
    $image_data = file_get_contents($_POST["image_url"]);
    $new_image_path =  "assets/images/product_image/" . rand() . "." . $extension;
    file_put_contents($new_image_path, $image_data);
    $message = 'Image Uploaded';
    $image = '<img src="../../'.$new_image_path.'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"  />';
    $image_link = $new_image_path;
        }
    else
        {
            $message = "Image not found";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'Invalid Url';
    }
    $output = array(
        'message'   =>  $message,
        'image'     =>  $image,
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

here is update function :

```
$upload_image = $this->upload_image();
$upload_image = array('image' => $upload_image);
$this->model_products->update($upload_image, $product_id);
```

Comment: Can you post the code of 'upload_image()' and 'model_products->update()'?

Comment: what do you mean by 'except it cannot insert to database'?